ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
We are facing this issue whenever we try to open the hyperlink manager in richtext it starts to throw the error.
I have checked the webconfig the Telerik dialogue handler is present.
Can you please help me resolve this?


Did you compare the assembly version of Telerik from a vanilla Sitecore instance with your instance in the web.config? May be the version is mismatched.
